# Stall Core-animation for Concurrent Core-graphics processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics, nsrunloop

I'm looking for a way to stall core animation until I can finish doing some processing in core graphics.  I've tried a few methods, but nothing seems to work.

**Background**:
I've got a lot of Core-Graphics drawing I need to do.  All of the processing is done in an ImageContext, so I render the images concurrently and once they're done I set the appropriate `layer.content` to the resulting image (on the main thread). The problem I have, is that often the current run loop will end before I'm done processing the images and core-animation will begin it's thing without all the proper view backgrounds in place (often displaying black backgrounds) during the animation.  I need a way to stall core animation until all the concurrent image processing is done.

I also do a lot of "stamping": caching the resulting image and returning it so I don't have to perform unnecessary processing.  I believe this rules out using `[CALayer drawInContext:]` and setting `drawsAsynchronously = YES;` since I don't want to reprocess the core-graphics for each view.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've tried using `performSelector` on a method that will "wait" (run an empty `while loop`) until the processing is done, but you can only either perform the selector immediately (too soon), or else in the next run loop using `delay` (too late).
- I've tried adding an observer to the main run loop:

Code:

```
    CFRunLoopObserverRef observer = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(NULL, kCFRunLoopAllActivities, YES, 0, ^(CFRunLoopObserverRef observer, CFRunLoopActivity activity) {
        [[Themes class] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(waitOnDraw) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES modes:Array(NSRunLoopCommonModes)];
    });
    CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetMain(), observer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

Note: `kCFRunLoopAllActivities` is overkill, but none of the other modes was working.  Just trying to cover all my basis.

If I could access the thread the core-animation runs on, maybe I could stall it directly, but I'm not sure how to access that thread.

And that's it... I can't think of any other way to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I know I could just run all the processing on the main thread, but I'm looking for as many performance gains as possible.  Processing the Core-graphics code concurrently really speeds things up on newer devices.

Comment: If your CA rendering cannot look right until you have the results of the CG drawing, then why do you start the CA animation so early? Why not start it after the CG drawing is done?

Comment: The animations and the drawings are very separate in the code.  Drawings are only refreshed when the bounds of the view changes, which may or may not be after an animation has been set.  Animations, on the other hand are done on the views and don't know anything about what's going on "under the view's hood".  Plus, a single animation may trigger a bunch of views to update their contents.  It can't really know which ones.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html

Comment: @robmayoff Now that's interesting... I'll have to look at that. It looks like you could pause the entire layer tree of the root view controller.  I'll mess around with that tomorrow.

Comment: @robmayoff  Nope, that didn't work.  It's a little better.  I get a black backgrounds in my views only at the very beginning of the animations.  However, I'm also getting a lot of weird graphical artifacts, distortions, etc. I may just have to find other ways of speeding up my drawings than by using concurrency.